# Php echo whole page HTML override

Tags: php, html, echo, eval

I am trying to make a specific webpage 'echo' an entire new HTML page while 'overwriting' anything that is set in the 'requested page'. Let's say that it has some form of content in it, I want the 'echoed' page to completely replace it, `<head>` tags and everything.
Similar concept is used (from what I understand) by various template engines. They however use a structured HTML and fill it with data, meanwhile I want dynamic creation of the HTML structure throughout the file, which will be aggregated into a string and then 'created' into an HTML to be displayed to the user.

```
<?php
    $htmlcontent = "\n";
    $htmlcontent .= "<html>\n";
    $htmlcontent .= "<head>\n";
    $htmlcontent .= "<style> body {\n";
    $htmlcontent .= "            background-color: red;\n";
    $htmlcontent .= "        }\n";
    $htmlcontent .= "</style>\n";
    $htmlcontent .= "</head>\n";
    $htmlcontent .= "<body>\n";
    $htmlcontent .= "<div style=\"background-color:yellow; width:200px; height:200px; position:absolute\"> Some text </div>\n";
    $htmlcontent .= "<script>\n";
    $htmlcontent .= "alert(\"script has run!\");\n";
    $htmlcontent .= "</script>\n";
    $htmlcontent .= "</body>\n";
    $htmlcontent .= "</html>\n";

    echo ($htmlcontent); //EDIT: removed eval() from here
?>
```

**EDIT:** *removed the eval() to avoid confusing the new people, put a comment for those reading post's comments to not get confused by the lack of eval in code.*

This is the content of the .php page that I am targeting with my request. The idea is, to be able to get an entire new page in the browser, what happens instead is an error that follows (now irrelevant because Eval is removed):

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' in
>   D:\wamp\www\learningPHP\index.php(30) : eval()'d code on line 2

If I just use:

```
echo $htmlcontent;
```

then I get the page to print out my HTML structure, however it is all printed in a body of a blank HTML page instead of being structured as I need it.

**Answer:**

The issue was with one of the plug-ins for NetBeans. Upon manually editing the .php file from the server it appears it was carrying the standard HTML tags of a document, as well as some comments on it as well. Removing these fixed the issue.

Comment: `echo`, `eval`, do you even understand what are you doing?

Comment: Why are you using eval?

Comment: PHP generates the HTML so just output whatever you want there. If it is outputting your PHP maybe you don't have PHP installed on your computer/server; or the handler isn't set up? In either case `echo eval` is wrong in this instance; `echo $htmlcontent;` should be what you use.

Comment: I am using echo to print the needed HTML/JS/CSS to the page that will be received by the client.
I tried using Eval on top of it as well and left it in there so that people reading know I tried doing it. From what I understand Eval is suppose to 'execute' the code inside of it. I am not sure if it will execute the <script> that I placed in there or not, but I tried messing with it and left it here so that people know I tried it and it didn't work. To avoid the "did you try eval()?" sort of answer, as a precaution.

I need the PHP to output the HTML exactly like that, and it doesn't.

Comment: Character limit, couldn't write more:
Just using simple 'Echo' almost does the trick, as I stated, but it doesn't override the main page's initial HTML, and that is the whole point.

Comment: A page doesn't have "initial html" unless it is being generated by something else you have running, like a template engine or framework of some sort. If that is all that's in your PHP file (eval notwithstanding), it should simply echo the HTML, unless there is something else at play. You could try setting a doctype with PHP like `header('Content-Type: text/html');` but I doubt if that is required here.

Comment: When I simply put: `echo $htmlcontent` everything is working great! Until I inspect the page to see the structure. Instead of having <style> in the head element, it is printed out in a body tag. This leads me to believe that any <?php ?> code I have in there gets "embedded" into an empty PHP page, instead of creating it's own page with it's own <head>, <body>, <html> tags. If you understand what I mean.

Comment: Even if your .php file looks as simply as:
`<?php
    echo 'Hello world';
?>`

The page that client gets still has <head>, <body> tags. I need those to be overwritten by what I put in the 'echo' statement. Or I need to use something other then an echo, but I don't know what???

Comment: Just a thought, have you tried Viewing Source rather than Inspecting? Chrome's inspector shows how the browser interprets the code rather than the original code itself. It could be that Chrome doesn't see any document type and tries to assign its own in the inspector. Maybe try adding `$htmlcontent .= "<!DOCTYPE html>";` before your <html> tag?

Comment: Both viewing the source and inspecting yield the same results. The browser 'embeds' the returned string within a blank .html page (let's call this blank page 'Charlie'), for the lack of better description. 

Tried putting the <!DOCTYPE html> as well, still behaves the same.

It simply ignores my <html>,<head> and <body> tags and puts my entire string into the Charlie's <body> tag.

Comment: Can you please provide the rest of the code, or meta information about what processes are running in addition to the provided PHP code? I ask because I ran the exact same source code (minus eval) on a LAMP server and it did nothing like what you describe. It produces an HTML document... so, you must have something else going on.

Comment: I am using WAMP. The only thing that is in the directory is a php file called index.php. The full structure of that file is displayed in my main post. (minus the eval() but I removed that from the post as well.).

The result is a page that looks exactly as it should, it has a div, it has colors, all is fine. But once I view source or inspect, the content of the <head> tag is not what it was in my `$htmlcontent` variable, or in other words what I wrote in the `$htmlcontent` regarding the <head> tag, or <body> tag, just simply doesn't get echoed. Screenshot:
https://yadi.sk/i/z8ytBcgumaqUv

Comment: looks like itis from or text editor you are using to edit php source or from wamp server - check wamp php configuratipon for autoprepend files

Comment: hmm you might be right, I am using net-beans and some plugins on top of it as well. Let me try to manually edit the file on the server.

Comment: When I echo this it gives me error on style tag location code written in double quotes under another double quote

Comment: Alright, it worked. After manually editing the .php files on the server it worked properly. It appears it has something to do with NetBeans or one of the plug-ins that was installed. Somewhere on the way from saving the development files and copying them to the server the files apparently do not get saved the same. Now all that is left to do is figgure that one out :P

Comment: NetBeans works fine - it's the case that you're not paying close enough attention to the actions you are taking.  There is no plug-in or anything that re-arranges your code.  The files will always be saved the same.  They are text files.  Ensure you had permissions to overwrite the files you think you are overwriting.

Comment: When I edited the file manually from the server with Notepad++ it appeared to have HTML structure around the <php> tags, even though there were none in NetBeans. IDK why, how, or when did these get 'attached' for the lack of a better word but once i removed them and made a clear PHP file, it started working.

Answer (score 1):

I read your question and your all comments.

I think you need `ob_start();`, it's simple and easy:

```
ob_start(); //write this line in start of your project, 
//In header file. 

//Here is normal html/css/js/PHP. write your html or echo any things...
// Normal code is here....

//e.g: 
<html><body>Hello world <?php date("y"); ?> </body></html>

$html = ob_get_clean(); //write this line at the end of file.. in footer file
//now your html save in $html variable,
now use replace functions to replace any thing from your html.. :)

//at the end, 
echo $html;
```

`ob_start();` when you use this function nothing will show on browser until you echo the result

```
$html = ob_get_clean();
echo $html;
```

Comment: I will try fiddling with it, but my issue is a lot simpler in nature.
First, there is no header.php, main.php and footer.php. It is all one same file and I have no need for it to be anything else (it will not be used as is, rather as part of a much larger system) but I have isolated this one .php file into a specific sub-domain (so to speak) to test it in an independent environment. All I really need is to output an HTML string of the entire page, the string is already in a variable, but instead of outputting the entire page, <head>, <html>, <body> it all gets mashed into <body>.

Comment: I see your snapshot that you post in other comment, may be this is from your browser, check your html output in source code of browser, right click on browser and open source code.. does your code ok in source code..? , if not ok then upload snapshot of your real code environment...

Comment: It appears that the enviroment was adding the needed code. Once I manually edited the .php file with notepad++ from the server it started working properly. Thanks for all your trouble!